# GDI+ HotKeyPrefix only on Alt key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I use the following code in custom button to draw the text inside an overridden `OnPaint` event:

```cs
// ...
Point TextPoint = new Point(2, 2);
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.HotkeyPrefix = System.Drawing.Text.HotkeyPrefix.Show;
e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), TextPoint, format);
// ...
```

This works fine and even respects the `&` hotkey. However, the underline that is normally shown underneath the hotkey (e.g `C&ancel` would become `Ca̲ncel`), which is normally only shown when the user presses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, is now always shown.
**Is there any way I can render this underline only when the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd> like on the default .NET button (`System.Windows.Forms.Button`)?**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.showkeyboardcues(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks!